# Issue in parsing moengage notification response in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, moengage

I am getting an issue in parsing Moengage notification response which is below  from

From:

```
   -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
{
  NSLog(@"notification appdelegate  %@",userInfo);
  [self customPushHandler:userInfo];

}
```

`notification app delegate: 
  {
    "app_extra" =     {
        screenData =         {
            "" = "";
        };
        screenName = "";
    };
    aps =     {
        alert = "iOS Test ";
        badge = 1;
        "content-available" = 0;
        sound = default;
    };
    moengage =     {
        "" = "";
        cid = ;
      };
    }`

```
- (void) customPushHandler:(NSDictionary *)notification {

 if (notification !=nil && [notification objectForKey:@"app_extra"] != nil) {
    NSDictionary* app_extra_dict = [notification objectForKey:@"app_extra"];

      NSDictionary* app_extra_dict1 = [[notification objectForKey:@"app_extra"]objectForKey:@"aps"];

      NSDictionary* app_extra_dict2 = [[notification objectForKey:@"aps"];

      NSLog(@"Moenage notification %@",notification);
      NSLog(@"Menage   apps  %@",app_extra_dict1);
      NSLog(@"Moenage apps %@",app_extra_dict2);               
      NSLog(@"Moenage %@",app_extra_dict );

   }
  }
```

Log:

> Moengage notification :Same as above response
>
> Menage   apps (null)
>
> Moenage apps (null)
>
> Moenage:

`{
  screenData =     {
   "" = "";
     };
     screenName = "";
     }`

Now my issue is I am trying to retrieve " aps =     {
        alert = "iOS Test ";" ..But this not is JSON..can any please suggest me to parse this response or is their way to retrieve  **"iOS test"** from this response

Comment: Where is the string from?

Comment: Please check my update now..From didReceiveRemoteNotification I m printing the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solved this by converting above response to Jsonstring and than to NSDictionary:

```
   - (void) customPushHandler:(NSDictionary *)notification {

 if (notification !=nil && [notification objectForKey:@"app_extra"] != nil) {

    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:notification
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"Got jsonString: %@", jsonString);

        NSError *jsonError;
        NSData *objectData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                             options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                               error:&jsonError];


         NSLog(@"json %@",json[@"aps"][@"alert"]);


    }

}
```

**Console:**

2016-01-29 12:28:06.613  json **iOS Test**

Comment: There is no need to convert the dictionary to JSON and then again getting the same dictionary. You will directly get the data using keys. I have integrated the SDK and have written the answer with the logs which I got while getting the notification.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the format you are getting data and there is no need to convert to JSON, you are already getting the data in a NSDictionary. Your answer where you are converting the dictionary to JSON and again converting the JSON for getting the same dictionary doesn't make any sense. You can simply access all the values by using the keys as below :

```
- (void) customPushHandler:(NSDictionary *)notification {

if (notification !=nil && [notification objectForKey:@"app_extra"] != nil) {

    NSDictionary* app_extra_dict = [notification objectForKey:@"app_extra"];
    NSDictionary* aps_dict = [notification objectForKey:@"aps"];

    NSLog(@"Moengage notification : %@",notification);
    NSLog(@"Moengage   appsExtra : %@",app_extra_dict);
    NSLog(@"Moengage aps : %@",aps_dict);
}
}
```

And below are the logs for the same :

```
    Moengage notification :  {
    "app_extra" =     {
        screenData =         {
            key1 = Val1;
        };
        screenName = Screen1;
    };
    aps =     {
        alert = "Hello!!!";
        badge = 1;
        "content-available" = 0;
        sound = default;
    };
    moengage =     {
        cid = 5715f243597b7b0f37a9254a;
        key1 = Val1;
    };
}

 Moengage   appsExtra :  {
    screenData =     {
        key1 = Val1;
    };
    screenName = Screen1;
}

Moengage aps :  {
    alert = "Hello!!!";
    badge = 1;
    "content-available" = 0;
    sound = default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to print like this:

```
- (void) customPushHandler:(NSDictionary *)notification {
    NSLog(@"notification:%@", notification);
    NSLog(@"Moenage:%@", notification[@"app_extra"]);
    NSLog(@"Menage apps:%@", notification[@"aps"]);
}
```

Comment: This is giving null as above response is not in json format..thank you..Solved this by conversion to JSON

Comment: So the response of server is invalid.

Comment: No, format of third part SDK (Moengage) response is this way..So We need to convert as required format..

Comment: @Sujania Does it work for apns when screen is locked?

Comment: it is only giving sound alert for notification of moengage, where as APNS notification is showing as message on lock screen